# Find orphaned subcollection documents

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

The firestore docs say:

> When you delete a document that has associated subcollections, the subcollections are not deleted. They are still accessible by reference. For example, there may be a document referenced by `db.collection('coll').doc('doc').collection('subcoll').doc('subdoc')` even though the document referenced by `db.collection('coll').doc('doc')` no longer exists.

Is there any way to access these documents if you lose the reference do `db.collection('coll').doc('doc')`? Say for example client A goes offline, and then creates `coll/doc/subcoll/foo`. Then the server deletes `coll/doc` and it's subcollections. Later client A comes back online and syncs foo. 
It appears that now there's now way for me to know that foo exists and is wasting space in the database.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to retrieve all documents of the sub-collection (including orphans) with `.collectionGroup('subcoll')`.

Then you can iterate over them with `.forEach()` and retrieve their parent with `.getParent()`.

If they don't have a parent, they are an orphan and you can delete them.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the access to these documents. Save IDs somewhere when users delete the documents. Or just find out the document ID in console.firebase.google.com. If you have ID of removed doc you will able to fetch the subcollection's docs. The removed doc ID marked italic in Firebase Console ([like this one](http://joxi.net/RmzGKjBhWa4v92)).

Comment: I accidentally ended up with hundreds of such documents mixed up among thousands of real documents. Manually finding and deleting all the sub collections is not a viable solution.

Comment: see : https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/355

Answer (score 0):

Adding a cloud function to delete subcollections when a doc is deleted, can help with this problem from occurring again. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections#cloud_function

```
exports.removeSubCollections = functions.firestore
.document("col1/{docId}")
.onWrite(async (change, context) => {
  const docId = context.params.docId;

  if(!change.after.exists) {
    //Delete all subcollections here
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you lose reference to the deleted document that contains the orphaned sub collection you want to delete, you will have to go to the firestore console. All deleted documents that still contain sub collections appear in *grey-itallics* as opposed to other document entries (id).

[image]

For deleting, you can

- Retrieve all the documents within the collection/subcollection and delete them (for larger collections, delete the documents in smaller batches). Preferably using a [callable cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections)
- Delete directly from the firestore console. Deleting a document from the Console deletes all of the nested data in that document, including any subcollections.
- Delete documents and collections from Firebase CLI with command `firebase firestore:delete [options] <<path>>`